tramp-sshfs remote command execution doesn't respect `tramp-remote-path` or `tramp-remote-process-environment`
Recently I noticed a new tramp protocol called sshfs was introduced in Emacs 28 and I decided to try it out. It works fine, and as I understand it, opening and editing remote files is done through the local sshfs mount, but remote command execution is done the regular way, which is good (i.e. it won't try to execute the remote binary locally through the local sshfs mount).
A major problem is that the sshfs protocol won't respect tramp's remote path/environment customizations. I noticed this while trying to execute magit, because my remote machine has a very old git version installed, so I needed to install a newer git version elsewhere and make the path point there. When I tried to run magit, it complained about git being too old and it failed.
I opened eshell to do some tests and confirmed my suspicions:

tramp-remote-path looks fine:

("/home/c/luizromario/emacs/bin" "/home/c/luizromario/.local/bin" tramp-default-remote-path "/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/local/bin" "/local/freeware/bin" "/local/gnu/bin" "/usr/freeware/bin" "/usr/pkg/bin" "/usr/contrib/bin" "/opt/bin" "/opt/sbin" "/opt/local/bin")

but...

git --version prints out: git version 1.8.3.1
which git prints out: /sshfs:luizromario@remote-machine:/usr/bin/git
echo $PATH prints out: /usr/bin

Editing tramp-remote-process-environment to add /home/c/luizromario/emacs/bin directly to the PATH variable has no effect.
This feels like a bug, but I'd like to know first if I'm doing something wrong here.

Tramp's sshfs method does not use tramp-remote-path.
